# Tests won't run after upgrading to Angular 6 w/ CLI

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, angular-cli-v6

Upgrade an Angular 5 project with webpack to Angular 6 using the Angular CLI.
The tests now don't run with the following error.

```
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4) ERROR
   An error was thrown in afterAll
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: env.catchExceptions is not a function
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.006 secs / 0 secs)
```

I changed my context in test.ts so that instead of running all of my tests it would just run a single test that I set up and it still fails with the same error.

test.ts

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import 'rxjs-compat';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.

// const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.fake-test\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

fake-test.ts

```
describe('fakeTest', () => {
    it('fakeAssert', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Here are the relevant versions in package.json

```
"@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
```

Here's some more logging with karma logging set to LOG_DEBUG:

```
15 05 2018 08:39:25.913:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /_karma_webpack_/scripts.js /
15 05 2018 08:39:25.913:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /_karma_webpack_/scripts.js
15 05 2018 08:39:25.914:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /_karma_webpack_/vendor.js /
15 05 2018 08:39:25.914:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /_karma_webpack_/vendor.js
15 05 2018 08:39:25.914:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /_karma_webpack_/main.js /
15 05 2018 08:39:25.914:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /_karma_webpack_/main.js
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.004 secs / 0 secs)
15 05 2018 08:39:26.139:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
15 05 2018 08:39:26.140:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
```

Here is a picture of my test runner in Chrome showing 0 of 0 tests.. but in the source on the right you can clearly see a test.

[image]

I have another new Angular 6 project that is using CLI and it is working.  I have been unable to identify any significant differences.

Comment: Can you try upgrading karma to `~2.0.0`?

Comment: in your test.js is `context.keys().map(context);` the last line ?

Comment: yes that's the last line.. trying karma 2.0.0 results in the same, I'll update the versions in the question

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a line in your test.ts that actually starts Karma:

```
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

Your test.ts should look something like this(Notice the last line):

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare let __karma__: any;
declare let require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
// tslint:disable-next-line
__karma__.loaded = function () {
  //leave this empty
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context: any = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

Comment: this is not required, I have a new project without __karma__.start() that works.. angular cli starts it under the hood.. the specs are not found for some reason, even though I see them in my source files (chrome debugger)

Comment: I heard that there are some compatibility issues between jasmine-core and karma-jasmine. try these versions and see  "jasmine": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1", "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",

Comment: thanks for the version info, @NadhirFalta. I also needed: "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2"

Answer (score 0):

So the regex is wrong, instead

`\.fake-test\.ts$`

is

`fake-test\.ts$`

basically you are waiting a "." before "fake" `.fake-test.ts`

I hope it will be helpful.